# Search using column value in bigtable cbt

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, cbt

Please confirm how can we search using column value using cbt shell in google bigtable.
Like in SQL , we have select * from tablename where column_name like '%%'

Answer (score 0):

You can perform filters on your Bigtable database on [column values](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#interleave) however if you are filtering your entire database, that be very inefficient, so you should try to scan a particular area of your database.

If you want to check if a particular column has a certain value, you will need to do an [interleave filter](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/using-filters#interleave) on the column name and value like this (in Java):

```
Filter filter =
  FILTERS
      .interleave()
      .filter(FILTERS.value().regex(YOUR_REGEX))
      .filter(FILTERS.qualifier().exactMatch(YOUR_COLUMN_NAME));
```

Comment: This is a good example for Java but does not answer the OP's question on how to do this with cbt a command line tool provided by Google to interact with a BigTable instance.